# How to ensure that two classes be always (re)compiled together in Java

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

While I was going through [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3), in the example section for final methods, it quotes:

> Such inlining cannot be done at **compile time** unless it can be guaranteed that Test and Point will always be **recompiled together**, so that whenever Point - and specifically its move method - changes, the code for Test.main will also be updated.

So how can one ensure that two classes can ALWAYS be compiler together.
One obvious example would be in case inner/nested classes we can say that they would be always compiled together.
What are the other ways?

Comment: hmm maybe initialising your classes in the constructor of your superclass. Or do a factory_pattern

Answer (score 0):

> So how can one ensure that two classes can ALWAYS be compiler together.

Your mistake is assuming that this is necessary. The text you quote only applies *compile time*.

At runtime the JITs will kick in and perform inlining anyway, no matter how the class files have been generated.

Comment: I am not assuming that its Necessary. But my question is if One wants to assure such a thing, How can it be done. What needs to be taken care? What type of code/pattern guarantees that?